# Works fine with firefox but have some issue with google chrome and browser resizing?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have created the menu. This works quite fine in firefox but in google chrome, the hover is not displayed. Also when I resize my browser part of the menu hides and is not scrollable, I tried with MENU `width:100%;`, but when I do this and resize the browser, the class layout is distorted and displays out of the line of menu, the menu is distorted. Is there anyway to solve this problem:
 so i forcefully define the width of the menu to 1366px to avoid menu distortion. Please help.

```css
#mainmenu {
    width:1366px;
    height:50px; 
    /*position:relative;*/
    position:fixed;
    top:18px;
    padding-left:200px;  
    line-height:50px;
    background:#0b2c3d;
    z-index:10;      
    box-shadow:5px 0px 15px #7e7a7a; 
}
#mainmenu, #dd_home, #dd_profile, #dd_achv, #dd_contact,#dd_login {
    cursor:pointer;
}
#mainmenu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;        
}
#mainmenu ul li {
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    /*border-right-style:dotted;*/
}
#mainmenu ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;           
    color:white;
}
#mainmenu ul li.home {
    width:150px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:-5px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #0a68fb;
}
#mainmenu ul li.home:hover {
    display:block;
    background-color:#0a68fb;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
#mainmenu ul li.profile {
    margin-top:-5px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #ed4901;
}
#mainmenu ul li.profile:hover {
    display:block;
    background-color:#ed4901;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
#mainmenu ul li.achv {
    margin-top:-5px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #27fb06;
}
#mainmenu ul li.achv:hover {
    display:block;
    background-color: #27fb06;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
#mainmenu ul li.contact {
    margin-top:-5px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #b70bfb;
}
#mainmenu ul li.contact:hover {
    display:block;
    background-color:#b70bfb;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
#mainmenu ul li.contact:checked {
    margin-top:-5px;
    border-bottom:10px solid #b70bfb;
}
#mainmenu ul li.login {
    margin-top:-5px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #36b096;
}
#mainmenu ul li.login:hover {
    display:block;
    background-color:#36b096;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
#mainmenu ul li.nepal {
    margin-top:-5px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #f8d605;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="about.aspx"> Home</a>
        <li class="profile"><a href="profile.aspx" >Profile</a>
        <li class="achv"><a href="achv.aspx">achievements</a>
        <li class="contact"><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a>
        <li class="login"><a href="login.aspx">Log in</a>
        <li class="nepal"><a href="#">jaya nepal</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** [jsfiddle.net/gzeLS](http://jsfiddle.net/gzeLS/)

Comment: yes i already shared my cod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `display:block` from your `:hover` styles:

[jsfiddle.net/gzeLS/1](http://jsfiddle.net/gzeLS/1/)

Or, add `display:block` to the non-hover styles:

[jsfiddle.net/gzeLS/2](http://jsfiddle.net/gzeLS/2/)

I'm not sure why Chrome doesn't like that.  I'd say it's a Chrome bug.

To get the menu to resize, do some work with `max-width` and `min-width`.  You'll only be able to get it about 600px wide before text starts overlapping.  Prevent overlapping by giving the menu a `min-width`.

[jsfiddle.net/gzeLS/3](http://jsfiddle.net/gzeLS/3/)

But then, as you've already discovered, part of the menu is hidden when the window is too small.  Even if you set a `min-width` on the body to get scroll bars to appear, you still won't be able to scroll the menu because you are using `position: fixed`.  Your best bet would be to use media queries to shrink the font size if the window is below a certain width.

[jsfiddle.net/gzeLS/4](http://jsfiddle.net/gzeLS/4/)

**Edit:** Here's a breakdown of the changes I made to get to [the third jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzeLS/3/) where centering works regardless of window size.

- To get the menu to fill the page, rather than specify `width`, specify `left` and `right`.
- To position the menu items in the center:

  - Use `text-align: center` on the menu, not `padding`.  This will account for different window sizes.
  - Set `display: inline-block` on the `ul` to make it centerable.
  - Set `width` and `max-width` on the `ul`.  Using `width` allows us to size the `li` elements by percent, which lets them shrink if the window is too small.  And `max-width` let's us actually center the menu items, giving the margin on the right and left when the window *is* wide enough to fit the menu at full width.
- To prevent the menu items from wrapping when the screen is too small, set `white-space: nowrap` on the `ul`.
- To prevent the text of the menu items from overlapping when the window is too small to fit the entire menu:

  - Set `min-width` on the menu.
  - Set `overflow: hidden` on the menu items.
- For simplicity, I also consolidate redundant styles from the list items by class into the `li` selector.

Here are the changes I made in [the fourth jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzeLS/4/) to get the menu to fit a smaller window and remain visible:

- Remove `min-width` from the menu to allow it to shrink to fit the window.
- Add media query styles to progressively decrease the font size as the window size decreases:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 640px) { #mainmenu { font-size: 90%; } }
@media all and (max-width: 590px) { #mainmenu { font-size: 80%; } }
@media all and (max-width: 530px) { #mainmenu { font-size: 70%; } }
@media all and (max-width: 468px) { #mainmenu { font-size: 60%; } }
```

Comment: But still confuse with second solution

Comment: @Milano - What specifically about the second solution confuses you?

Comment: @Milano - I added a detailed description of what changed.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you make this small change, for example on the home link:

```
#mainmenu ul li.home:hover
```

**TO**

```
#mainmenu ul li.home a:hover
```

Then you'll notice that your hover properties are properly displayed in Chrome and Firefox.

[JSFiddle for this fix](http://jsfiddle.net/MQ7D6/)

**UPDATE**

[And here's a fix for your second problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/MQ7D6/1/)

You need to set the `text-align` of your master div to `center` in order to center a `ul` within a container.  The typical `margin: 0 auto;` won't work.  I added a `white-space:nowrap;` as well to prevent breaking when the screen is smaller than the horizontally aligned menu items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.. thank you very very much.. this worked for me.. once again thank you very much

Comment: If this worked, please be sure to mark it as your answer.  Thanks!